# Serialized Assembly Won't Upload to Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, serialization, clr, sqlclr

I have a CLR project that calls a simple HTTP web service. Its x64-targeted and I got it to serialize properly only after going through the steps outlined at the following link which talks about the changes required to have VS2010 point to the correct target architecture (x64) - the changes just required unloading and changing the .csproj file with a few extra lines to reference the correct version of sgen.exe: http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2011/12/10/148002.aspx

Now, I am able to build this project and its .XmlSerializers.dll by setting "Generate serialized assembly" to on. I wanna do this because my CLR project is going to get deployed on the database, and I don't want it to runtime serialize any objects since those DLLs are not referenced in my database and I don't want to give my CLR project permissions higher than EXTERNAL_ACCESS for security reasons because this will be used in a production environment where security is important, and also because my database is NOT trustworthy.

Long story short, I am following the guide at the following link to upload my serialized assembly into the database but I get an error: http://footheory.com/blogs/bennie/archive/2006/12/07/invoking-a-web-service-from-a-sqlclr-stored-procedure.aspx

The error is: CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly '.XmlSerializers' failed because the assembly is built for an unsupported version of the Common Language Runtime.

Does anyone know how to correct this by forcing sgen.exe to serialize a CLR-supported version of the assembly? Viva the Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was actually not the fact that I'm using .NET 3.5 as a target, but I was referencing the wrong version of the sgen.exe tool, which in this case I needed the x64 version of 6.0A (which translates to .NET 3.5) at this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\sgen.exe. Now I am able to build the correct version of the serialization assembly, upload it, and also use it.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2 supports only .Net 2.0. You need to change your project to target this, see [How to: Target a Specific .NET Framework Version or Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx). You do *not* need to specify x64 for the build target, SQLCLR assemblies should be Common target built.

That said, calling web services from SQLCLR is a **really really really bad idea**. Don't do it. Have an external process handle the HTTP calls.

Comment: I found that the problem was actually not the fact that I'm using .NET 3.5 as a target, but I was referencing the wrong version of the sgen.exe tool, which in this case I needed the x64 version of 6.0A (which translates to .NET 3.5) at this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\sgen.exe. Now I am able to build the correct version of the serialization assembly, upload it, and also use it.

Comment: Also, I would not say this is a bad idea at all to have CLR invoke a .NET Web Service. I am restricting my CLR to run under a user account with EXTERNAL_ACCESS permissions. The DLL is strong-name signed and the user account is mapped to an asymmetric key for this DLL. Its very secure. Only two DLL files had to be imported into the database: the CLR and the serialization DLL for the CLR, which helps serialize the generated proxy class using the wsdl tool, in which I had kept only the constructor and synchronous methods. Its scary how secure it is.

Comment: Since the DLL contains a Web Reference, the DLL files it loads in are already supported by MSSQL Server, so I did not need to import other DLL files like you would for creating a proxy to a WCF service. Also, the only unfortunate downside to me using x64 as a target architecture was that I had to manually reference assemblies for x64 so that my project would build by unloading it and editing the .csproj file.

Comment: The problem with SQLCLR doing HTTP access is that is going to steal one of the most precious and restricted SQL Server resources, a [worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and block it waiting for a HTTP response. One day you'll come to work to find your production database *frozen*.

Comment: Note that .Net 3.5 and .Net 2.0 are really the very same thing, the '3.5' name is only a marketing gimmick. The important difference is not to have your assembly targeted for .Net 4.0, which would work only with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Firstly, I use a trigger to call my CLR assembly method, so at most a table will freeze for a very short duration of time. Secondly, I can specify the ServiceProxy.Timeout to wait for synchronous calls to complete. All my calls are synchronous...so my static CLR method will always return. In the worst case, one table is frozen for a short duration (the table my trigger is on). Yes, 3.5 is an extended version of 2.0 which use a lot of the same libraries as 2.0.